# Trying to figure out how to delete a user in ASP.Net

Tags: c#, html, css, asp.net-mvc, visual-studio

What am I doing wrong?

Here is the code in my UserManager:

```
public static int Delete(Guid id, bool rollback = false)
{
    try
    {
        int results = 0;
        using (ReciMeEntities dc = new ReciMeEntities())
        {
            // Prepare to create a transaction if the function/data will be rolled back
            IDbContextTransaction dbContextTransaction = null;
            if (rollback) dbContextTransaction = dc.Database.BeginTransaction();

            // Create a new row that grabs a data row from the table
            tblUser row = dc.tblUsers.Where(u => u.Id == id).FirstOrDefault();

            // If fetch was successful, update row data
            if (row != null)
            {
                dc.tblUsers.Remove(row);
                results = dc.SaveChanges();

                // Rollback data if condition met
                if (rollback) dbContextTransaction.Rollback();
            }
            else
                throw new Exception("Row does not exist");
        }
        return results;
    }
    catch (Exception ex) { throw ex; }
}
public static int DeleteAll()
{
    try
    {
        using (ReciMeEntities dc = new ReciMeEntities())
        {
            dc.tblUsers.RemoveRange(dc.tblUsers.ToList());
            return dc.SaveChanges();
        }
    }
    catch (Exception ex) { throw ex; }
}
```

Here is my UserController Delete code:

```
public ActionResult Delete(Guid id)
{
    UserManager.Delete(id);
    return RedirectToAction(nameof(Index));
}

// POST: UserController/Delete/5
[HttpPost]
[ValidateAntiForgeryToken]
public ActionResult Delete(int id, UserVM userVM)
{
    try
    {
        return RedirectToAction(nameof(Index));
    }
    catch
    {
        return View();
    }
}
```

****Here is my HTML:****

```
<div class="row gutters-sm" style="width:100%; text-align: center">
    <div class="col-md-4 mb-3">
        <div class="card">
            <div class="card-body">
                <div class="d-flex flex-column align-items-center text-center">
                    <img src="https://atlasfamilyhealthcenter.com/wp-content/uploads/2017/12/blank-avatar.png" alt="Admin" class="rounded-circle" width="150">
                    <div class="mt-3">
                        <h2>
                            @HttpContextAccessor.HttpContext?.Session.GetString("fullname").Replace("\"", "")
                        </h2>
                        <input type="submit" value="Reset Password" class="btn btn-primary" />
                        <br />
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
    <div class="col-md-8">
        <div class="card mb-3">
            <div class="card-body">
                <div class="row">
                    <div class="col-sm-3">
                        <h6 class="mb-0">Full Name</h6>
                    </div>
                    <div class="col-sm-9 text-secondary">
                        @HttpContextAccessor.HttpContext?.Session.GetString("fullname").Replace("\"", "")
                    </div>
                </div>
                <hr>
                <div class="row">
                    <div class="col-sm-3">
                        <h6 class="mb-0">Email</h6>
                    </div>
                    <div class="col-sm-9 text-secondary">
                        @HttpContextAccessor.HttpContext?.Session.GetString("email").Replace("\"", "")
                    </div>
                </div>
                <hr>
                <div class="row">
                    <div class="col-sm-3">
                        <h6 class="mb-0">Status</h6>
                    </div>
                    <div class="col-sm-9 text-secondary">
                        @HttpContextAccessor.HttpContext?.Session.GetString("accesslevel").Replace("\"", "")
                    </div>
                </div>
                <hr>
                <div class="row">
                    <div class="col-sm-3">
                        <h6 class="mb-0">All Saved Recipes</h6>
                    </div>
                    <div class="col-sm-9 text-secondary">
                        <a asp-action="">All Saved Recipes</a>
                    </div>
                </div>
                <hr>
                <div class="row">
                    <div class="col-sm-3">
                        <h6 class="mb-0">All Created Recipes</h6>
                    </div>
                    <div class="col-sm-9 text-secondary">
                        <a asp-action="">All Created Recipes</a>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>

<div style="width:100%; text-align:center">
    <p>
        @{
            Reci_me.BL.UserManager.Seed();


            if (description != null)
            {
                <a asp-controller="User" asp-action="Logout"><input type="submit" value="Logout" class="btn btn-primary" /></a>
                <a asp-controller="User" asp-action="Edit" asp-route-id=@HttpContextAccessor.HttpContext?.Session.GetString("id").Replace("\"", "")><input type="submit" value="Edit Account" class="btn btn-primary" /></a>
                <a asp-controller="User" asp-action="Delete" asp-route-id=@HttpContextAccessor.HttpContext?.Session.GetString("id").Replace("\"", "")><input type="submit" value="Delete Account" class="btn btn-primary" /></a>
            }
        }

    </p>
</div>
```

Can anyone help with this?

Comment: Do you see any error message? Please remove the try/catch and let the exception to be visible. Also calling _throw ex_ is an effective way to destroy the call stack information that could reveal the exact line that causes an exception. Instead just log the exceptions with some log manager library

Comment: No I don't see any error message.

Comment: Is it possible that you are looking at a different database? What is the connectionstring used?

Comment: You have tried to break the point to troubleshoot, which is the basic skill of every program developer. You can refer to [Troubleshoot Breakpoints in the Visual Studio Debugger](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/troubleshoot/developer/visualstudio/debuggers/troubleshooting-breakpoints). This will help you solve many problems.